# How can we sort based on the number of matched filtered

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, comparable

Can someone help us with regards to sort based on the number of matched filtered. We need to prioritized the number of matched filtered on **SKILLS** rather than *(skills + training / skills + certification)*

In the table below, it shows that after we sort based on the PRIMARY SKILL TYPE, the system get the combination of Skill + Training. How to resolve this?  [image]

```
    // wrapper for results
    global class pageFilter implements comparable {

    public Contact employee{get;set;}
    public pageFilter other {get;set;}

    public List<Employee_Skills__c> empSkillList{get;set;}
    public List<Employee_Training__c> empTrainingList{get;set;}
    public List<Employee_Certification__c> empCertificationList{get;set;}

    //related list of skill, training and Cert
    public List<Employee_Skills__c> relatedSkillList{get;set;}
    public List<Employee_Training__c> relatedTrainingList{get;set;}
    public List<Employee_Certification__c> relatedCertificationList{get;set;}     

    public String nameOfSkill;
    public String profOfSkill;
    public String yoeOfSkill;
    public String typeofSkill;   
    public String nameOfTraining;   
    public String nameOfCertification;
    public String nameOfEmployee;

    public void transferName (){
        if (empSkillList != null) { 
            for(Employee_Skills__c eSkill : empSkillList){
                this.nameOfSkill = eSkill.Skill_ID__r.Name;
                this.profOfSkill = eSkill.Proficiency__c;
                this.yoeOfSkill = eSkill.Year_of_Experience__c;
                this.typeOfSkill = eSkill.Skill_Type__c;
            }

        }

        if (empCertificationList != null) {           
            for(Employee_Certification__c eCertification : empCertificationList){
                 this.nameOfCertification = eCertification.Certification_ID__r.Name;   
            }               
        }

        if (empTrainingList != null) {           
            for(Employee_Training__c eTraining : empTrainingList){
                 this.nameOfTraining = eTraining.Training_ID__r.Name;   
            }               
        }


        if (employee != null) {
            this.nameOfEmployee = employee.Name;
        }


    } 

     // Grouped based on the number of matched filter 
    public integer totalCount { 
       get {                     
            transferName();                         
            Integer skillCount = (empSkillList == null) ? 0 : empSkillList.size();
            Integer certificationCount = (empCertificationList == null) ? 0 : empCertificationList.size();
            Integer trainingCount = (empTrainingList == null) ? 0 : empTrainingList.size();

            return skillCount + certificationCount + trainingCount;                                       
        }                      
    } 

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    pageFilter compareToFilter = (pageFilter)compareTo;
    pageFilter other = (pageFilter)compareTo;
        if(this.totalCount < compareToFilter.totalCount) {
            return 1;
        } else if(this.totalCount > compareToFilter.totalCount) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return compareToFields(other);
        }                       

    }

   // sort the 3 custom field based on the requirements        
   Integer compareToFields(pageFilter other) {
       String skName = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).nameOfSkill : ''; 
       String skProf = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).profOfSkill : '';
       String skYoe = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).yoeOfSkill : '';   
       String skType = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).typeOfSkill : '';   
       String trName = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).nameOfTraining : '';
       String certName = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).nameOfCertification : '';
       String empName = other != null ? ((pageFilter)other).nameOfEmployee : '';

        if(this.typeOfSkill <> skType) {
            return this.typeOfSkill.compareTo(skType);
        } else{
            if (this.nameOfSkill <> skName){                   
                return this.nameOfSkill.compareTo(skName);                   
            } else {
                if(this.profOfSkill <> skProf){        
                    return skProf.compareTo(this.profOfSkill);
                } else {
                    if (this.yoeOfSkill <> skYoe) {
                        return skYoe.compareTo(this.yoeOfSkill); 
                    } else {
                        if (this.nameOfCertification <> certName) {
                            return this.nameOfCertification.compareto(certName);         
                        } else {
                            if (this.nameOfTraining <> trName) {
                                return this.nameOfTraining.compareTo(trName);
                            } else {
                                if (this.nameOfEmployee <> empName) {
                                    return this.nameOfEmployee.compareto(empName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }            
        }

   return 0;          
   }


} // end of pageFilter comparable
```

Comment: Can you provide a simpler example of the sort order you are wanting? Generally speaking you can just adjust the `compareTo` method as required.

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger we're trying to search for 2 skills and 1 training from the table result above. 

The contact/employee record that has 2 skills should appear first before the the contact/employee record that has 1 skill and 1 training regardless of its skill type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we're trying to search for 2 skills and 1 training from the table result above. The contact/employee record that has 2 skills should appear first before the the contact/employee record that has 1 skill and 1 training regardless of its skill type.

You need to compare first by the skill type and then by the sum of the remaining factors.

E.g.

```
public Integer skillCount {
    get { return (empSkillList == null) ? 0 : empSkillList.size(); }
}

public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    pageFilter compareToFilter = (pageFilter)compareTo;

    // Compare based on skills alone initially.
    if(this.skillCount  < compareToFilter.skillCount ) {
        return 1;
    } else if(this.skillCount > compareToFilter.skillCount ) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Perhaps only compare the combined certificationCount and trainingCount
    if(this.totalCount < compareToFilter.totalCount) {
        return 1;
    } else if(this.totalCount > compareToFilter.totalCount) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return compareToFields(compareToFilter);
    }                       

}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel Ballinger, what if we searched for 2 Training, 1 certification and 1 skill. We need to prioritized also matched result with **2-training over 1-training/1-certification and 1 training/1skill.**

Comment: same with certification. If we searched for 2 Certification, 1 Training and 1 skill. we need to prioritized **2-Certification over 1-training/1-certification and 1 certification/1skill.**